# Creating a program to read from a text file and count the number of 5's. output is off by one five

Tags: java

When I run the program everything seems to work fine except that it counts 8 fives when there are in fact 9 fives in the txt file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileIO2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String filename = "Input1.txt";

    Scanner myFile = null;
    try
    {
        myFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);  //close the program
    }


    int countNums = 0;
    while(myFile.hasNext())
    {
        if(myFile.hasNextInt(5))
        {
            countNums++;
        }
        myFile.next();  
    }
    System.out.println("There were " + countNums + " fives in " + filename);
    }
}
```

Input1.txt file contents:

5 9 3 2 0 5 3 0 8 5 5 5
5 9
4 3 0 6
5 5 5

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
myFile.hasNextInt(5)
```

From the documentation of the [hasNextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt-int-) method:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as an int value in the specified [radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) (base) using the nextInt()
>   method.

So that doesn't return true if the next int value is 5 as you expect. *It will return true if each digit in the number (and each number in this case has just one digit) is **between 0-4** (radix 5)!*.

So change your while loop to:

```
while(myFile.hasNext())
{
    if(myFile.hasNextInt() && myFile.nextInt() == 5)
    {
        countNums++;
    }
}
```

This time we validate that the number is actually 5 using [hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) without arguments (which uses radix 10, i.e. the decimal system) and [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) which returns the given number.

Comment: Turns out OP has counted anything else except fives and bigger.

Comment: @AlecA please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do some refactor on your code.

This solution works fine:

```
public class FileIO2 {
    private static final String PATH_TO_FILE = "/home/user/temp/Input1.txt";
    private static final int NUMBER_TO_FIND = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int counter = 0;

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(PATH_TO_FILE))) {
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int currentInt = scanner.nextInt();
                if (currentInt == NUMBER_TO_FIND) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("There were " + counter + " fives in " + PATH_TO_FILE);
    }
}
```

The problematic line in your code is `myFile.hasNextInt(5)`.